# (continuous) deployment from dropbox to github or gitlab pages?

Tags: github, deployment, synchronization, dropbox, gitlab

Host a website with jekyll on github pages. The folder with posts should be available from dropbox, so that if dropbox gets a modified or new file within that folder, the github website gets updated.

Is this possible? I may have a solution with zapier but I'd rather have a better way of doing this.

Comment: Check out http://deploybot.com and also maybe Aerobatic.com and Bitbucket.